# class stepper 2 arguments 1 instance

Tags: python, class

I am making a class motor. It will control setup a motor so it will be easyer to control.

This is what I would like to do.

```
class robot(object):

def __init__(self, addr=0x60, port, revolution, speed):
    self._mh = Adafruit_MotorHAT(addr)
    self._stepper = self._mh.getStepper(port, revolution)
    self._speed = self._mh.setSpeed(speed)
```

I does not work and gives me a syntax error a non-default argument follows default argument. This is because I have 2 arguments that I use in one instance. I could make a def setup and it would work.

```
    self._mh = Adafruit_MotorHAT(addr)
    self.port = port
    self.revolution = revolution
    self._speed = self._mh.setSpeed(speed)

def setup(self):
        self._mh.getStepper(self.port, self.revolution)
```

But I would like to have it in the initiation part so I do not have to call motor.setup().

So is ther maybe a nicer way to do this than adding a method to the class? So it would be in the methode **init**.

Comment: The error message seems quite clear: you have non-default arguments after a default argument. Why do you not do the obvious thing, which is to swap them round?

Comment: @Daniel Can you specify for me what the default argument would be. (The addr perhaps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a non-default arguments means that you have given it a value. 
for example: `addr=0x60`
You have to place these non default arguments after the normal arguments.
Like this:

```
def __init__(self, port, revolution, speed, addr=0x60):
    self._mh = Adafruit_MotorHAT(addr)
    self._stepper = self._mh.getStepper(port, revolution)
    self._speed = self._mh.setSpeed(speed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Required arguments come before optional arguments in function signatures.